# Android Call Web Service for Login Page

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, call

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on calling Web Services while passing in parameters.  I have found a plethora of tutorials dealing with creating a web service as well as calling a web service without passing any parameters, but that isn't doing me any good at this point.  I'm using ksoap for this.  Does anyone know of any half decent tutorials for something like this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the ksope library you can follow up this tutorial.

http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html

Some of the basics are available.